# Failed to push local changes

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with Git and Github. So:

1.I pushed a commit from other device

2.On local machine, I forgot to do **git pull**

3.Made changes to files

4.Made a commit, and tried to push, but git complained about refs

5.So I tried **git fetch**, and then **git pull** but it complained about conflict files.

6.Then I tried **git pull --rebase** and then **git rebase --skip**.

7.After that, I tried **git pull --ff-only**

8.Now Git refuses to "see" all changes I made on step 3

What I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem started when you ran `git rebase --skip`. That told Git to ignore the commit that had conflicts.

To fix this, go back to the state before the rebase. Do a `git reflog` and look for the entry right before the rebase, then do a `git reset --hard` to that commit.

Now run the rebase again, but instead of skipping, try to resolve the conflicts you had. Then `git add` the file with conflicts, and do `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: > Now run the rebase again should I just do git rebase with no args?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But git removed index.html file in my public folder, so I had to restore it from backup.

Comment: However you ran it before. That'll work if you have the branches associated as an upstream (`master` -> `origin/master` for instance).